# How to write a code that distinguishes if there is '0' in existing file, or new generated file

Tags: c

I've been working on code that:

  1. checks if "sample.txt" exist, if not ,generate a new file,

  2. if file already exist, check if first line has single '0'. if not, truncate and write '0'

Below is what i've written so far. however the iszeroOrnewfile always turns into 0 so don't go into different case. Am i approaching this correctly?

```
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #define buf 128
   int main (int argc, char** argv)
   {   
       int fd;
      char buff[buf]={0} ;
      int iszeroOrnewfile=1;
      int iszero=0;
      if(!(argv[0]>0))
          printf("insert positive integer");
      fd = open("./sample.txt",O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
      pread ( fd,buff,buf,0);
      for (int i=0;i<buf;i++)
      {   
          if((0 != buff[i]) || ('0' != buff[i]) )
              {   iszeroOrnewfile = 0;}       
          if('0' == buff [i]);
              { iszero = 1;}

      }
      if (iszeroOrnewfile == 1 )
      { 
          if (iszero !=1)
          write(fd, "0",strlen("0"));
      }
      else if(iszeroOrnewfile ==0)
      {
          truncate ("./sample.txt" , 0);
          write(fd, "0",strlen("0"));
      }

  }
```

Comment: `((0|'0')` - what are you trying to do here?

Comment: you have to check, how many bytes pread has read. Currently, you seem to assume that `buf` bytes have been read.

Comment: I'm not sure if i can just make it unconditionally instruction said that tho.

Comment: by (0|'0')  I was trying to see if there's char or int other than initial value 0, or allowed value '0'  ex) if file has '3' in first line , thats not 0 or '0' so its not zeroOrnewfile

Comment: Revisit how the `|` operator works.  It does bitwise or of two integer operands.  You don't get syntactic shorthands in C.  Your test is probably just for "is the first character a `'0'` and the next character a newline".  Although you don't write the newline.  It's odd to write the 0 to the file without adding a newline, though it is not automatically wrong.  Remember that `pread()` and `read()` and friends do not return strings; they return arrays of bytes (which may contain null bytes in the middle and may not have null bytes at the end).  Don't use string operations on arrays of bytes.

Comment: As a general guideline, please don't post line numbers in code on SO.  It makes it fiddly to take the code and compile it.

Comment: `if ((0|'0') != buff[i])` -> `if ( (0 != buff[i]) || ('0' != buff[i]) )`, but there are most likely more errors.

Comment: thanks I separated like walz said, but iszeroOrnewfile is still 0. I think my logic is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code may be useful:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define buf 128


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd;
    char buff[buf]={0} ;
    int iszeroOrnewfile=1;
    int iszero=0;
    int isFileCreated = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int i;
    if(!(argv[0]>0))
        printf("insert positive integer");
    fd = open("./sample.txt",O_RDWR);
    if(fd==-1 && errno==ENOENT)
    {
        //File dosen't exists
        isFileCreated = 1;
        fd = open("./sample.txt",O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
        write(fd, "0",strlen("0"));
    }
    else
    {
        len = pread ( fd,buff,buf,0);
        for (i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if((0 == buff[i]) || ('0' == buff[i]) )
            {
                iszero = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(len==-1 || iszero)
        {
            truncate ("./sample.txt" , 0);
            write(fd, "0",strlen("0"));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for giving me the insight of how to express when the case when file doesn't exist. however if file has other than '0' (ex contains '3') it doesn't change to '0' after excution.

Comment: If file has other than '0' then you have to truncate or have to change the whole content to '0'?

Comment: Truncate and change to 0 !

Comment: It turns out it is just to open with O_TRUNC but thanks for your insight